# How to get Top 3 of an int Array and display values in Listbox / ListView

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, streamreader, streamwriter

I was wondering how I can find the top 3 Transaction in Amount after interest from a textfile using arrays. Basically when the app opens, it loads the Top 3 Customers and Their cash value corresponding to their name in a list box or list view box.

In the Text File there are many numbers such as Transaction Number, Cash Deposit Amount, Cash Amount After Interest. How Do I differentiate those so it just finds the top 3 in cash amount after interest and also displays the name?

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    Console.WriteLine("transactions.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    int largest = array[9];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        if (array[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = array[i];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The largest transaction amount is {0}", largest);
    Console.Read();
}

//Here is the code for whats in the transactions.txt file.
public void CreateFile()
{
    StreamWriter outputFile;
    outputFile = File.AppendText("transactions.txt");
    outputFile.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("Total Amount" + " " + TotalAmountLabel.Text);
    outputFile.WriteLine("");
    outputFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: curious to know if this solved / helped you ? btw interesting question and goes for up vote :)

Comment: cash amount after interest is the result of sum of Initial Amount and Total Interest in your file?

Answer (score 2):

following changes you need to do  get you top 3

- variable largest to be int array `int[] largest`
- use `OrderByDescending` to sort the array in descending order
- use `Take(3)` to get the desired transactions
- msg variable is just for shorter code, else the code window on stackoverflow needs scroll

hope this helps,

```
int[] largest = array.OrderByDescending( item => item).Take(3).ToArray();
int count = 1;

string msg = "The {0} largest transaction amount is {1}";

foreach (var element in largest)
{         
    Console.WriteLine(msg, count++,element);   
}
```

---

Here is sample code for both listbox and listview

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99, 22, 44 };
   int[] largest = array
                    .OrderByDescending(item => item)
                    .Take(array.Length).ToArray();

     foreach (var element in largest)
     {
           listBox1.Items.Add(element);
           listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(element.ToString()));
     }
}
```

and this is how it looks this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sorry if this is really obvious but how would i get this information into the listView?

Thanks again

Comment: sure, update your question with details on what and how you want to show in listbox i will get you something on that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading each line into an object / struct instance, then getting the top 3 using something like

new List([if you still used an array to hold them]).OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount).Take(3);